# My CPU hits 100°C... Help me!

Tags: cpu, temperature, cooling

The safe limit for processors is typically 50°C or so, but I have found that my CPU likes to do up to 100°C.
I have got these readings from SpeedFan 4.42.
I have a Intel Quad Core unclocked.
I am using the standard intel fan with heatsink that came with the prossesor
My case is a Cooler Master and I have two fans installed on the case. I took the side off to see if that helped. It lowered the temp be 3C.

I don't really want to blow the processor and I don't know how to cool it down.

I applied some fresh thermal paste and it refused to boot up. After an hour of messing around with the wires it now works again. sill geting the same tempurature readings though but i officialy dont care anymore. it hasnt died yet and and hopefully never will.

Comment: Get a CPU cooler and fan.

Comment: Yes, what CPU cooler are you using?  How much thermal paste did you use?

Comment: the standard Intel fan heatsink. Not much termal paste

Comment: @JamesT - Please add the additional details from your comments into the question.

Comment: Do the temperatures out of CoreTemp (http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) agree with Speedfan?  I've never been convinced by Speedfan personally...  CoreTemp uses the actual thermal sensors in the CPU package to get the temperature.

Comment: CoreTemp reads the tempuratures to be 10C higher than SpeedFan.

Comment: Was the PC home-built? 
Is it a new build, or one that used to run cool but now is hot?
Where are you getting the temp readings from?

Comment: it is a home build. I am getting the readings from SpeedFan 4.42

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taking the side off a case can actually worsen things, depending on the design of the case.

also, what is your actual CPU utilization? are you encoding lots and lots of video? does it only hit this temp occasionally?

First thing, for the time being, underclock your CPU to make it run cooler.
then, did you put thermal paste between the CPU and the Heatsink? Was it a good quality one? or something that came as part of a kit?

Secondly, make sure all vents are clear of lint, pet hair, etc.

Also, make sure your fans are pointing in the correct direction. it does not help if you have one in front, and one in back, and they are both blowing into the middle.  if needed, re-arrange items inside the case to ensure the 'flow' of air from the incoming vents to the exhaust vent.

Comment: removing the side lowers the temp by 3C

Comment: @JamesT ^ Then the air flow in case is screwed up. I would Upvote Brian because you should follow all the above advice but I'm out of votes for today.;.

Comment: removing the side lowers the temp by 3C. i do quite a bit of 3D moddeling. It sits around 100C when using the programs so yes, quite frequently I used the thermal paste that came with the CPU but i will buy a better one to see if that helps. the vents are

Comment: @JamesT It still sounds like there is a airflow issue you in your case. I would check you fans and how they are setup, 100c is ridiculous I don't care what your doing.

Comment: @Kyle - This is so hot I can't see it being an airflow issue in the case.  The heatsink is mounted wrong or has too much thermal paste on it, you should be able to put a PC in a concrete enclosure and not have the processor get THAT hot in a fairly short amount of time unless something else is amiss.

Comment: @shinrai I was just saying that is one of many symptoms, originally I said he should follow all of the above advice I'm sure there are plenty of issues with this build...

Comment: @Kyle There are no issues with this build, provided its intended use is "cooking eggs in an igloo". ;)